# Parse HTML output to local file?

Tags: javascript, c#, html

I'm a beginner coder, I've only been coding for about a year or two.
I've begun to code a bot for fun, this bot generates random attributes for a games character creator (a very detailed one).
It is a plain text HTML file with no CSS, every time you reload the page, it generates a new bunch of attributes using some javascript RNGs.
For example,
Hair: 5
Hair Color: 43
and so on for every option.

The problem is that these characters take a long time to make by hand, and I was wondering how I would even begin to go about automating the process.
The first step in my mind would be to find a way to capture the output on the page and save it in a local file.

From there, I plan on creating a second program that reads the file in question and turns the file lines into controller inputs.

The following is a pastebin of -exactly- what the page looks like.
Again, there's absolutely no CSS so its plain as can be.
https://pastebin.com/QTUJiV2G

Each line of HTML is generated each by a slight variant of the following code, which I understand is not efficient, but was easiest way for me that allowed individual parameter changes for each setting.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    var min=1; 
    var max=29;  
    var random =Math.floor(Math.random() * (+max - +min)) + +min; 
    document.write("Face Texture: " + random );  
</script>
```

So I just need to find a way to output that to a file.
I'm somewhat familiar with C# so that would be the easiest for me to understand, but if there's a better way, I'd like to learn.

Thank you for reading!

Comment: `Hair: 5 Hair Color: 43` this looks suspiciously similar to JSON. Have you considered saving this data as JSON instead of HTML? Parsing JSON into an object is pretty trivial, then from an object structure you can generate HTML.

Comment: @mason the Hair: 5 and Hair Color: 43 on the page would be on different lines (not that i think it would matter too much to a program, its just for ease of reading). I've never looked into JSON at all, are you saying that instead of saving it as a HTML, if I saved it as a JSON it would output a file instead of opening a new tab on my browser to display the results?

Comment: In a browser environment you cannot directly save a file to disk (since that would be a gross security risk, if any random website could write files onto your device), but you can offer a file for to user to choose whether to download it. Or you could send data to the server to save the files there instead. Depends on the functionality you need. If you google "javascript create and download text file" you'll get quite a few examples of the former. If you google "ajax" you can start learning about the latter.

Comment: Appearing on different lines if a UI implementation detail. But if you stop thinking about it in terms of HTML and instead thing of it in terms of objects (for example, a Person has Hair type of 5 and Hair Color of 43) and [JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) is a means of describing those objects, this problem will be much easier.

Comment: " if I saved it as a JSON it would output a file instead of opening a new tab on my browser to display the results?" ...not directly, no. I think the point was just that JSON as a file format is more easily machine-readable than HTML. HTML is intended as means to display information nicely to humans. JSON is a simple data-interchange format. So the program which receives these files would be able to read them far more easily (most programming languages now can ingest JSON  files with a single line of code using a built-in function), since it's just a list of the objects and their properties.

Comment: Right, so, if i fiddled with it to make a nice JSON file, that would be a much easier jumping-off point than trying to make a program that could grab text from a browser screen? That makes sense.

Comment: That would be a lot easier yes. It would also be a lot easier than getting your program to parse a .HTML file and extract the data from it (which in turn would be 1000 times easier than trying to read data from a running browser application). [this article](https://blog.scottlowe.org/2013/11/08/a-non-programmers-introduction-to-json/) introduces the basics of JSON quite nicely. You can find 1000 other resources online too. JSON is very popular these days as it's simple to use and a reasonably efficient format (in terms of size of files etc).

Comment: Thanks I'll definitely have to look into that before i move forward then, thanks

Comment: P.S. In JavaScript itself if you want to create some JSON from a variable you've working with, just use `JSON.stringify()` e.g. `var person = { "Name": "ADyson82", "Occupation": "Web Developer" }; var jsonString = JSON.stringify(person);` . You could then offer the contents of `jsonString` for download with a .json file extension.